# How to scrape youtube comments using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie. i would like to know how to web scrape YouTube comments using BeautifulSoup . I am struck over here. can any one help me with the code.

here is what i have written :

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4"    
req =r.conten    
soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')    
print(soup.prettify())    
all = soup.find_all('div',{'id' : 'contents'})
```

I was stuck here not getting any output, inspecting the wb page it showed comments has id = contents

Comment: Is this to learn `BeautifulSoup`, or do you need to interact with Youtube? You could use Youtube's API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list

Comment: Hi, @Robert Seaman .I am learning `BeautifulSoup` and trying to get youtube comments to practice. which i am feeling very hard to do . can you help me with this?

Comment: There are easier pages to use to learn `BeautifulSoup`.  Fancier sites like youtube often load the page via javascript, so if you just use `requests.get` you're not going to see much data.  Perhaps try using `w3schools.com` or `example.com`?

Comment: also, please format your code, this snippet cannot be run via copy paste because it's incomplete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment of that site are generated dynamically. You can't get them using the main link making use of `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` library. To get the content tracking the above link you need to use any browser simulator like `selenium`. As a starter, you can try like below. The following script will fetch you the unwrapped comments. Btw, the site also has got lazyloading method active so you need to twitch the `for loop` to get more content.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

with Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4")

    for item in range(3): #by increasing the highest range you can get more content
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body"))).send_keys(Keys.END)
        time.sleep(3)

    for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#comment #content-text"))):
        print(comment.text)
```

Partial output:

```
15 April 2018 ?¿?
April 2018??
8 years people 
Nice songs Justin Bieber https://youtu.be/OvfAc7JGoc4
2018 hit like...♥️♥️♥️♥️
8 years complete 
Can likes beat dislikes??
View 1, 8 billion great song
```